# How to shrink a histogram plot in R

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a histogram with a normal curve and legend but there isn't enough space. The normal curve goes outside the plot area and the legend is forced to curve up bargraph due to limited space.

```
normality_plot <- function(datapoints) {
hist(datapoints[[2]][[1]],freq = F, las = 1,main=paste("Histogram of ", datapoints[[1]][[1]]), 
   xlab="Value", 
   border="black", 
   col=" light blue")
   curve(dnorm(x, mean = mean(datapoints[[2]][[1]]), sd = sd(datapoints[[2]][[1]])), add=TRUE, col = "darkblue",lwd=3)
   legend(x = "topright", 
     c(paste("Mean = ", mean(datapoints[[2]][[1]])), paste = "Std = ", "N"),xpd=TRUE)
}
```

[My graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etcJa.png)

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: You will need to specify the `ylim` in the `hist` function.